# Spring @Autowired annotation giving null for dozer mapping

Tags: annotations, autowired, dozer

Here is my class I am trying to use this annotation and I am getting null for dozerBeanMapper. I also get null for other beans I am trying to use like Jaxb2Mapper, etc

```
@Service("Transformer")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Transformer {

@Autowired
private Mapper dozerBeanMapper;

public Object testMethod(Object wlpData) throws TransformerException {

    MbrReq destObject = null;

    destObject = dozerBeanMapper.map(request, MbrReq.class);

    return destObject;
}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
<sws:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxx.xxxx.srvc.membership,com.xxxxx.xxxx.interact.membership.request,com.xxxxx.membership.ws,com.xxxxxx.srvc.membership.generated,com.xxxxx.xxxx.service.transform" />

<!-- WSDL Exposed as memberService  -->
<bean id="searchMemDemographics" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/schema/MemSvc_Binding_HTTP_V0100.wsdl"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:mapping/dozer-global-configuration.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:mapping/dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.xxxxx.srvc.membership" />

 <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="reqMarshaller" contextPath="com.xxxxxx.membership.request" />

 <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="respMarshaller" contextPath="com.xxxxxx.membership.response" />
```

In web.xml I have this

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
           classpath:spring/membershipApplicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Anything else I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id to the bean.

`<bean id="dozerBeanMapper" class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">`